# How to save a Singleton Object to an XML file using JAXBContext?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, singleton

I am looking to save a Singleton Object to an XML file using JAXBContext. The Object in question is called Player which is extending an abstract class Entity. Entity does also extend Thread. Since Player is a Singleton Object, its constructor is made private and and unaccessible from outside the class.
How can I do this properly?

Here is the piece of code I use to save the Player:

```
public static void savePlayer() throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Player.class);
        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        OutputStream os = null;
        try {
            os = new FileOutputStream(StringConstants.PLAYER_SAVE_FILE);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        m.marshal(Player.getInstance(), os);
    }
```

And here the piece of code to read it out again:

```
public static Player readPlayer() throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Player.class);
        Unmarshaller u = context.createUnmarshaller();
        File f = new File(StringConstants.PLAYER_SAVE_FILE);
        return (Player) u.unmarshal(f);
    }
```

On both classes Entity and Player I used the following anotation:

```
@XmlRootElement
```

Richt above the start of the classes.

Here is the error output I get:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.lang.Thread$UncaughtExceptionHandler is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at java.lang.Thread$UncaughtExceptionHandler
        at public java.lang.Thread$UncaughtExceptionHandler java.lang.Thread.getUncaughtExceptionHandler()
        at java.lang.Thread
        at model.entities.Entity
        at model.entities.Player

    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:91)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:445)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:277)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:124)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1123)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:147)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:247)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:234)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:462)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:641)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:584)
    at model.io.SaveWriter.savePlayer(SaveWriter.java:20)
    at tests.SaveTest.main(SaveTest.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.lang.Thread$UncaughtExceptionHandler is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at java.lang.Thread$UncaughtExceptionHandler
        at public java.lang.Thread$UncaughtExceptionHandler java.lang.Thread.getUncaughtExceptionHandler()
        at java.lang.Thread
        at model.entities.Entity
        at model.entities.Player

    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:91)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:445)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:277)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:124)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1123)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:147)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:247)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:234)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:462)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:641)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:584)
    at model.io.SaveReader.readPlayer(SaveReader.java:18)
    at tests.SaveTest.main(SaveTest.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Comment: Did you use  @XmlElement  annotation in your Player class setters ? You need to mark what exactly you want to marshall. You can find more on this tutorial: http://www.java2blog.com/2013/02/jaxb-tutorial.html

Comment: Well so far I didn't as the Player class has currently no setters (except the ones in the Entity class it extends). I thought the problem was the instantiation of the JAXBContext. Both Player and Entity classes lack a public constructor. I tried applying the annotation you mentioned, but that did not change anything in the error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found the issue. As explained in the question the class Player extended the class Entity. **The class Entity extended the common Thread class**. Apparently the JAXBContext cannot be properly instantiated for a Thread Object. I fixed this issue by letting the class Entity implement the **interface Runnable**, what left me with no more errors whatsoever.